# Html recebido através do HttpClient do c# com erro de caracteres especiais

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Mesmo usando Encoding, HttpUtility.HtmlDecode e WebUtility.HtmlDecode o erro continua persistindo.

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AllowAutoRedirect = true,
                
};
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html;charset=utf-8");//ACCEPT header
    string responseBody = "";
    try
    {
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); 
        var bytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        responseBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
        Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
    }

    return responseBody;
```

[Html com erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLurM.png)

Eu queria que html viesse sem esses erros.

Estou usando .NET 5

Comment: Verifique se no cabeçalho da requisição, você está passando charset.
Ex: `content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8`.

Comment: Não funcionou tentei aqui @BrunoWarmling

Comment: Inclua mais informações, quais cabeçalhos http está usando, como está salvando o resultado, qual versão do .net está usando entre outras coisas mais que julgar necessário.

Comment: Adicionei mais detalhe @BrunoWarmling

Comment: Troca o método e tenta usar o `ReadAsStringAsync`, não da pra assumir que o retorno do html está em `UTF8`. Ainda com as mudanças, faltam informações.

Comment: O método é isso, eu só faço uma requisição para receber um html, o estranho que no navegador vem tudo ok. Testei pelo postman e vem também com esse caracter "coringa" @BrunoWarmling

Comment: ao debugar, `responseBody` está recebendo os acentos corretamente? o campo html em que a informação é exibida também está como _"utf-8"_?

Comment: o responseBody já vem com o erro, e o campo html que é exibido também está com utf8. @rLinhares

Comment: Mas então o problema é no site? Abrindo pelo navegador, ele exibe esses caracteres "coringa"?

Comment: Eu consegui achar a solução, eu só continuei com o código acima, e troquei UTF8 por LATIN1 e foi. @BrunoWarmling

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de ser `responseBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);` troquei o UTF8 por latin1 `responseBody = Encoding.Latin1.GetString(bytes);` e veio os caracteres corretos.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).